# Detect touch screen in iOS

Tags: ios, gesture, touchscreen

Now I have implemented the fling feature in my ios app,  but I want to stop the fling when a touch on screen happens, this does not only contain tap gesture, maybe other like long press or pinch, I have a BOOL value to indicate whether a touch happens, so should I add all kinds of  gesture recognizers and set to BOOL value as true? Are there any simple solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods in `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` that will achieve what you want. `gestureRecognizerShouldRegognizeSimultaneouslyWithGesture` sounds like the best candidate. You will get passed two gesture recognizers. One will be your swipe gesture (the one you want to keep), the other will be the one you want to cancel (tap, long press, pinch) return NO in the correct scenario.

See docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate